# discord.js bot for replacing ","

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js, bots, message

i'm creating a discord bot with node.
I would like that when a user sends a message with the prefix "doc", it replaces all the "," with a random word between "word1" "word2" "word3" etc ...
I don't know this field well. I got to this point and I don't know how to do it:

```
bot.on("message", async message => {
  if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.channel.type === "dm") return;

  let prefix = botconfig.prefix;
  let messageArray = message.content.split(" ");
  let cmd = messageArray[0];
  let args = messageArray.slice(1);

  //replace ","

});
```

Comment: [`replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) can take a function as a replacement, so you can `replace(/,/g, (m) => { ... })`

Comment: ok, how i implement replace() with discord.js standards? (i don't know javascript)

Comment: I don't know what "discord.js standards" are.

Comment: i don't know how it works

Comment: You're going to have to learn a bit of JavaScript to solve this. You can't just get magical internet code for it.

Comment: it was enough for me to know this, the only thing I need. And i didn't want to study all javascript. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I arrived at this point:

```
var words = [" word1 "," word2 "," word3 "," word4 "," word5 "," word6 "];


bot.on("message", async message => {
    if (message.content.includes("doc ")) {

      if(message.content.includes(",")){
        var txt = message.content.replace(/doc /gi, "");
        var rando = Math.floor((Math.random() * 6) + 1);
        var txt = txt.replace(/,/gi, words[rando]);
        
        message.channel.send(txt);

      }else{
        message.channel.send("the text doesn't contain any comma");
      }

    }
```

---

input:doc I met Harry, we went for a swim together, and afterwards Harry went home.

---

output:I met Harry word5 we went for a swim together word5 and
afterwards Harry went home.